# PHP Curl return error 400 after 5-10 request

Tags: php, curl

I have a php curl doing a post request to an API, everything seems ok until some request.

After 5-10 requests the curl return me error 400 but the data is store to the API DB, I'm logging the data returned by the curl ussing `curl_getinfo();` the unique different between the others responses is the 'header_size' and I don't know how to resolve this, can some one help me?

here is my curl code:

```
$cookiestore = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '_cookiejar_');
        $headers = array(
            'Accept' => 'application/xml',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/xml',
            'Content-Length' => strlen(trim($xml)),
            'User-Agent' => 'spider',
            'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, must-revalidate'
        );

        $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
        session_write_close();

        $ch = curl_init(trim($url));
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT    => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
            CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => trim($xml),
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSLCERT        => $cert,
            CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD  => $cert_pass,
            CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE    => 'pem',
            CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION  => true,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => $cookiestore,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => $cookiestore,
            CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT  => true,
            CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE   => true,
        );

        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $xmlRes = curl_exec($ch);

        $res = (object)array(
            'response'  =>  $xmlRes,
            'status'    =>  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE),
            'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo($ch),
            'errors'    =>  curl_error($ch)
        );

        curl_close($ch);
```

My curl_getinfo() log:

Request working perfectly

```
'status' => 200,
     'info' => 
    (object) array(
       'url' => 'https://sifen-test.set.gov.py',
       'content_type' => 'application/soap+xml',
       'http_code' => 200,
       'header_size' => 1694,
       'request_size' => 16191,
       'filetime' => -1,
       'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
       'redirect_count' => 0,
       'total_time' => 1.891777,
       'namelookup_time' => 0.006782,
       'connect_time' => 0.014785,
       'pretransfer_time' => 0.077833,
       'size_upload' => 16004.0,
       'size_download' => 618.0,
       'speed_download' => 326.0,
       'speed_upload' => 8463.0,
       'download_content_length' => -1.0,
       'upload_content_length' => 16004.0,
       'starttransfer_time' => 1.89161,
       'redirect_time' => 0.0,
       'redirect_url' => ''
```

Same request Response after 5-10 request:

```
'status' => 400,
     'info' => 
    (object) array(
       'url' => 'https://sifen-test.set.gov.py',
       'content_type' => 'text/html',
       'http_code' => 400,
       'header_size' => 1560,
       'request_size' => 16172,
       'filetime' => -1,
       'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
       'redirect_count' => 0,
       'total_time' => 10.155684,
       'namelookup_time' => 0.001246,
       'connect_time' => 0.009627,
       'pretransfer_time' => 0.070932,
       'size_upload' => 16004.0,
       'size_download' => 326.0,
       'speed_download' => 32.0,
       'speed_upload' => 1575.0,
       'download_content_length' => -1.0,
       'upload_content_length' => 16004.0,
       'starttransfer_time' => 10.154854,
       'redirect_time' => 0.0,
       'redirect_url' => '',
```

I sent the same xml with the same data, is working perfectly but after 5-10 requests I get error 400, I thought the problem was the server limit, but it's not because I'm not always get that error after 5-10 requests sometime is in the first attempt or in the second.

Comment: What did you already try? We do not know what you found on google, so the information:  _"I  already try everything what I found in google"_ is kind of void.

Is it your own API and are maybe hitting a request limit? Did you look into the actual response of the API, despite a 400 there should be an actual error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

To further debug your CURL request, you can try with this code:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_errno($curl);
$errmsg = curl_error($curl) ;
$header = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$header['errno'] = $err;
$header['errmsg'] = $errmsg;
$header['response'] = $response;
print_r($header);
```

Comment: it's Debugged me the same debug what I posted